# Is it possible to use clang std library in gcc compiler?

Tags: android, gcc, c++11, clang

I working on android project and I need to access the wstring_convert class in c++11 in gcc but the problem is gcc does not have this in its standard library, so am thinking of using clang std library in gcc compiler of this possible, or if there is any other way to use wstring_convert from external library like stlport but stlport development latest update is in 2008 !

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```

in your **Application.mk**

Answer (score 1):

The standard C++ library from the LLVM project is:

http://libcxx.llvm.org/

It is a standalone, separate project from clang, but I never heard of someone using it with GCC. There are parts of the standard library which rely on compiler-specific internals (e.g., some type traits), so I am not sure this is going to work.

**edit**

From the front page:

> libc++ is known to work on the following platforms, using g++-4.2 and clang (lack of C++11 language support disables some functionality). Note that functionality provided by  is only functional with clang.

So it looks like it might actually work with at least some versions of GCC.